# Enum generated classes are Final or Not?

Tags: java, enums, code-generation, extends, final

When I specify an enum like this:

```
enum Color { RED }
```

The generated code `javap -p Color` looks like this:

```
final class Color extends java.lang.Enum<Color> {
  public static final Color RED;
  private static final Color[] $VALUES;
  public static Color[] values();
  public static Color valueOf(java.lang.String);
  private Color();
  private static Color[] $values();
  static {};
}
```

However, when I add custom extensions like an explicit constructor, e.g.:

```
enum Color {
  RED,

  Color() {}
}
```

I get this:

```
class Color extends java.lang.Enum<Color> {
  public static final Color RED;
  public static final Color Color;
  private static final Color[] $VALUES;
  public static Color[] values();
  public static Color valueOf(java.lang.String);
  private Color();
  private static Color[] $values();
  static {};
}
```

Missing the `final` modifier for generated class Color. However, I cannot extend `Color` (as usual):

```
final class B extends Color {}
```

The compiler gives:

```
error: enum types are not extensible
final class B extends Color {}
      ^
1 error
```

So why is the `final` modifier missing when adding custom code to the enum class? I suppose the prevention of subclassing Color anyway is performed by a sanity check from the compiler (aka: if super class typeof enum => deny), right?

I am using `OpenJDK 17.0.2`

Answer (score 7):

You did not add an explicit constructor here:

```
enum Color {
  RED,

  Color() {}
}
```

Instead, you added another enum constant, called `Color`, *with an empty class body*. This is evident in the unexpected line in the `javap` output:

```
public static final Color Color;
```

Therefore, an (empty) anonymous class has to be created, that inherits from the enum class, to serve as the class for the enum constant "`Color`". Therefore, the enum `Color` cannot be final. You should see an extra `Color$1.class` in the javac output folder.

Whether an enum should be final is stated in the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9) as follows:

> An enum class is either implicitly final or implicitly sealed, as follows:
>
> - An enum class is implicitly final if its declaration contains no enum constants that have a class body (§8.9.1).
> - [...]

The enum `Color` has the enum constant `Color` that has a body, so it is not `final`.

The correct way to add a constructor to an enum is to separate it from the constants using a `;`. `,` is used to separate constants. Example:

```
enum Color {
  RED, GREEN, BLUE;

  Color() {}
}
```

And as expected, this `Color` enum is `final`.

Answer (score 1):

Explicit `final` modifier isn't allowed with *enum classes*, because in fact they are **not final**.

That allows to "extend an *enum class* internally" by creating subclasses representing its *enum constants* under the hood. And these sublasses in turn are `final`.

According to the [Java language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.1):

> The optional class body of an **enum constant implicitly declares an anonymous class** (§15.9.5) that (i) is a **direct subclass** of the immediately **enclosing enum class** (§8.1.4), and (ii) is **final** (§8.1.1.2). The class body is governed by the usual rules of anonymous classes;

I.e. every *enum constant* can provide an optional *class-body* enclosed in curly braces `CONSTANT_NAME{ body }`. Which in fact is an implicit declaration of an *anonymous inner class* which extends the enclosing *enum class*. And as with a usual anonymous class, it's possible to override the behavior of the parent class.

Also note that because as a matter of fact every `enum` is extendible (*but not in the same way as a regular class can be extended*), it's possible to declare `abstract` methods within an `enum`. If there's at least one such a method, it needs to be overridden by the anonymous class of every *enum constant*, i.e. every *enum-member* has to declare an optional class body for that.

Let's explore it with an example:

```
class EnumTest {    
    public enum StringProcessor {
        UPPER {
            @Override
            public String process(String str) {
                return str.toUpperCase();
            }
        },
        LOWER {
            @Override
            public String process(String str) {
                return str.toLowerCase();
            }
        },
        REMOVE_DIGITS {
            @Override
            public String process(String str) {
                return str.replaceAll("\\d+", "");
            }
        };
        
        public abstract String process(String str);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(StringProcessor.REMOVE_DIGITS.process("27test_string"));
        
        System.out.println("Enclosing enum :\t" + StringProcessor.class);
        System.out.println("Enclosing UPPER :\t" + StringProcessor.UPPER.getClass());
        System.out.println("Enclosing REMOVE_DIGITS :\t" + StringProcessor.REMOVE_DIGITS.getClass());
        System.out.println("classes of enum members are the same : " + (StringProcessor.UPPER.getClass() == StringProcessor.REMOVE_DIGITS.getClass()));
    }
}
```

Will give the output:

```
test_string
Enclosing enum :    class _classpath_.EnumTest$StringProcessor
Enclosing UPPER :   class _QUESTIONS.ClassDisign.EnumTest$StringProcessor$1
Enclosing REMOVE_DIGITS :   class _classpath_.EnumTest$StringProcessor$3
classes of enum members are the same : false
```

If it was allowed to declare `enum` as final explicitly, the mechanism you see above will not work.

And at the same time it is for forbidden to extend `enum` class, although it's technically not final because `enum` is meant to represent a set of well define elements and base enum has to be aware of all of them.